# Error ] Expected in Methods

Tags: java

I'm not sure why I can't set the arrays to j or g to compare? Is there a smarter way to do this?

I have no issues until the make gradeExam and makeMissedArray methods. The if statements are getting these errors

```
DriverTest.java:72: error: ']' expected
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                 ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: ')' expected
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                  ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: ']' expected
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                                              ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: ')' expected
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                                               ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: not a statement
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                                     ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: ';' expected
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                                                ^
DriverTest.java:72: error: illegal start of expression
                        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
                                                                          ^
```

Code:

```
public static void main (String [] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String passedExam = null;
char[] studentAnswers = new char[20];
char[] answerKey = {'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'}; 


    // make the string for the answers
    collectStudentAnswers(studentAnswers);

    //change the answers to uppercase
    answersUppercase(studentAnswers);

    //comapre the two strings with i=0 to 20
    gradeExam(answerKey, studentAnswers);
    makeMissedArray(answerKey, studentAnswers);

    passedExam(gradeExam);

    System.out.printf("** Correct answers: %f", 20 - gradeExam);
    System.out.printf("** Incorrect answers: %f", gradeExam);
    System.out.printf("** %s", passedExam);
    System.out.printf("You missed the following questions:\n ");
    System.out.println(Array.toString(makeMissedArray));


    } public static void collectStudentAnswers(char[] studentAnswers){

        for (int i = 0; i < 20;){

    System.out.printf("Question %d:\n ", i + 1);
    char[] studentAnswers = input.next().charAt(0);

    i++;

    } 

    return studentAnswers;

    } public static char[] answersUppercase(char[] studentAnswers){

        studentAnswers.toUpperCase();
        return answersUppercase;


    } public static String passedExam (int gradeExam) {

        if (20 - gradeExam >= 15){

            passedExam = "You passed the exam.";

        } else {

            passedExam = "You failed the exam!";

        }

        return passedExam;


    } public static int gradeExam(char[] answerKey, char[] answersUppercase){

        for (int j = 0; j < 20;){


        if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){

            gradeExam++;    

            }   

        }

        return gradeExam;
        j++;        

    } public static int[] makeMissedArray(char[] answerKey, char[] answersUppercase){

        for (int g = 0; g < 20;){

            if (char[g] answersUppercase != (char[g] answerKey){

                makemissedArray[j] = g;


            }

            g++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `if (char[j] answersUppercase` means? What are you trying to say?

Comment: Don’t start your methods on the same line as the closing brace of the previous; it makes it much less readable.

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought that the statement called the j slot in that array.

Comment: @notyou Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply incorrect syntax:

```
if (char[j] answersUppercase != (char[j] answerKey){
```

Aside from the mismatched parentheses, this is not how you access an element of an array.

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
if (answersUppercase[j] != answerKey[j]){
```

But even after fixing that, there are several other problems (and a few oddities that aren't "wrong", just not idiomatic) in your code.

Might I suggest you would benefit from reading a Java tutorial, particularly about arrays and for loops.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Yes I definitely need to do more research, im fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your if like this

```
if (answersUppercase[g] != answerKey[g]){.....}
```

In your methods